# Python - How can I strip clear my string of trailing spaces when I am using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I am fairly new to programming, and python is my first language. I am learning on my own so maybe I am missing something. Sorry, if I could not word my problem properly.

I have written a function that accepts any number between 0-99 and converts it into mandarin based on a dictionary. Here is the function:

```
trans = {'0':'ling', '1':'yi', '2':'er', '3':'san', '4': 'si','5':'wu', '6':'liu', '7':'qi', '8':'ba', '9':'jiu', '10': 'shi'}

def convert_to_mandarin(us_num, flag = True):
'''
us_num, a string representing a US number 0 to 99
returns the string mandarin representation of us_num
'''
    if len(us_num) == 1:
        if us_num != '0':
            return trans[us_num]
        elif flag:
            return trans[us_num]
        else:
            return '\b'
    elif len(us_num) > 1:
        if us_num[0] == '1':
            return trans['10'] +' '+ convert_to_mandarin(us_num[1:], False)
        else:
            return trans[us_num[0]] + ' ' + trans['10'] + ' ' + convert_to_mandarin(us_num[1:], False)
    else:
        return convert_to_mandarin(us_num[:-1], False) + trans[us_num[-1]]
```

But for number ending with 0, the string is being returned with a trailing space. For example if n = convert_to_mandarin('10') then it returns n = 'shi '
but I want it to be n = 'shi'
So how can I get rid of the trailing space?

Answer (score 1):

you insert a space and try to delete it using backspace. But that is no good in files or debug.

Don't return anything where you returned the backspace, and strip the added strings afterwards to get rid of trailing spaces using `str.rstrip`:

```
trans = {'0':'ling', '1':'yi', '2':'er', '3':'san', '4': 'si','5':'wu', '6':'liu', '7':'qi', '8':'ba', '9':'jiu', '10': 'shi'}

def convert_to_mandarin(us_num, flag = True):
    '''
    us_num, a string representing a US number 0 to 99
    returns the string mandarin representation of us_num
    '''
    if len(us_num) == 1:
        if us_num != '0':
            return trans[us_num]
        elif flag:
            return trans[us_num]
        else:
            return ''
    elif len(us_num) > 1:
        if us_num[0] == '1':
            return (trans['10'] +' '+ convert_to_mandarin(us_num[1:], False)).rstrip()
        else:
            return (trans[us_num[0]] + ' ' + trans['10'] + ' ' + convert_to_mandarin(us_num[1:], False)).rstrip()
    else:
        return convert_to_mandarin(us_num[:-1], False) + trans[us_num[-1]]
```

(sometimes a post-correction is easier than trying to figure out how to avoid the problem, specially with recursion. Note that `rstrip` returns the same string if no replacement done, so the overhead is negligeable)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about rstrip. I actually tried the same thing with strip but didn't work since I was returning a ' ' instead of ''.

Comment: `strip` would also work, but is unnecessary because you only have spaces on the right side. You were returning a `\b` which is not stripped by `strip/rstrip`

Comment: Oh no. I tried it before the backspace, but since I was returning a space instead of an empty string it was not working. Wrong reasoning on my part.